# I can only make a cookie have one value in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have recently taken on a concept new to me in Web Development: cookies.

I understand that when you assign document.cookie a value, you are essentially creating a string.

However, when I run this simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="makeCookie()">
        <script>
            function makeCookie(){
                document.cookie = "value=4; pi=3.14"
                alert(document.cookie);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It alerts "value=4" instead of the "value=4; pi=3.14;" that I want it to alert.

How can I fix this, or, are there any easier alternatives to storing data even when the user leaves the page in JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How exactly does document.cookie work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791944/how-exactly-does-document-cookie-work)

Comment: The easier option would be `localStorage`

Comment: @adeneo Yes, this seems to be easier than cookies.  I will see which one is more efficient in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only set one cookie at a time. To assign multiple cookies, do separate assignments:

```
function makeCookie() {
  document.cookie = "value=4";
  document.cookie = "pi=3.14";
  alert(document.cookie);
}
```

Within a cookie assignment, `;` is used to add optional attributes, e.g.

```
document.cookie = "value=4; max-age=900";
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/09Lqyerd/)

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'm very new to this, as you can see.